# Is each good topological 3-orbifold homeomorphic to a CW-complex?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Suppose a group $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously by homeomorphisms on a 3-manifold $M$. Thurston observed that $M/\Gamma$ has the structure of a (topological) orbifold. (This generalises to any dimension.)

What can be said about $M/\Gamma$ as a topological space?
In particular,

**Question 1:** Is $M/\Gamma$ always homeomorphic to a CW-complex?

I think this is equivalent to asking whether $M$ admits a triangulation that is invariant under the action of $\Gamma$.

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, Bing's involution provides a negative answer. The remaining question is

**Question 2:** Must the singular locus of $M/\Gamma$ be homeomorphic to a CW-complex?

I’m not assuming $M/\Gamma$ is compact, but don’t mind doing so if it helps.

Remark: I know that if $\Gamma$ acts *smoothly,* then the answer to Question 1 is yes, because every smooth orbifold has a triangulation.

Comment: Isn’t Bing’s involution a counterexample to the first assertion?

Comment: I am not certain what theorem of Thurston's you are citing.  Are you assuming $\Gamma$ is finite, or some other hidden assumption?

Comment: I'm citing Proposition 13.2.1 in p. 302 of Thurston's lecture notes "The Geometry and topology of three-manifolds", available at This proposition says: If M is a manifold and G a group acting properly discontinuously on M, then M/G has the structure of an orbifold.

Comment: Thurston is likely (implicitly) assuming that the group action is smooth, otherwise, the orbifold claim is false, as noted above. But, indeed, every 3d orbifold (correctly defined) admits a triangulation.

Comment: @HJRW: I'm not sure what you mean by "first assertion", but I think Bing’s involution does give a counterexample to my question, so thanks!

Comment: Next question: is the singular locus of $M/\Gamma$ homeomorphic to a CW-complex?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: it seems to me he is explicitely saying that the action need not be smooth. See the beginning of section 13.2 and the proof of said proposition. I don't yet see why Bing's involution is a counterexample to his proposition.

Comment: Keep in mind that Thurston's Princeton Lecture Notes are an unfinished product, based on notes written by Thurston's students. In section 13.4, orbifolds are implicitly assumed to be smooth. Regardless, the modern version of orbifolds requires the local model actions of finite groups to be linear. In section 13.2 Thurston does not have such requirement, accordingly, Proposition 13.2.1 is correct as stated.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: thanks for explaining this! Anyway, we can talk about $M/\Gamma$ (and its singular locus) without calling it an orbifold, and I'm interested in an answer to my new question in the comment above.

Comment: If my intuition is correct, the quotient of $S^3$ by Bing's involution should be homeomorphic to the union of the horned sphere and its interior. According to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) the latter is topologically a 3-ball, in particular homeomorphic to a cell complex. So Bing's involution at least doesn't seem to lead to a counterexample.

Comment: @HJRW: from what I'm reading, you are using the wrong side of the horned sphere; Bing's involution uses the exterior, which is not a 3-ball, see e.g. https://lamington.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/bings-wild-involution/

Comment: @Agelos: Yes, I think you're right -- apologies, my mistake.